# Is there an overview of rules differences between various editions of Tunnels and Trolls?

Tags: edition-comparison, tunnels-and-trolls

There are several versions of Tunnels and Trolls available, with a good deal of variation in the format between them. Is there a good summary of the changes between the different versions?

(I'm especially interested in the more modern releases: 5.5, 7, The "alternate" system from 7, 7.5, 8, and Deluxe.)

Answer (score 11):

I can only speak to editions 4 onward...

## 4th Ed:

- attributes on 3d6
- Attributes ST DX CN IQ LK CH
- Types: Warrior, Wizard, Rogue
- Weapon damages presume 1d for daggers, 0D unarmed
- Combat Adds on St, Dex, Lk
- Rogues have a level limit; at cap, change class to warrior or wizard
- No spell schools
- Level by total EP
- Saving rolls presumed to be LK; other stats optional
- Saving rolls fail on natural rolls of 3 (⚀⚁) and 4 (⚀⚂) that aren't doubles

## 5th Edition:

- attributes on 3d6
- Attributes ST DX CN IQ LK CH and optionally SP
- Types: Warrior, Wizard, Rogue, Warrior-Wizard
- Weapon damages presume 1d for daggers, 0D unarmed
- Combat Adds on St, Dex, Lk
- No spell schools
- Weapon damages hit "modern" levels; 1d unarmed, 2d daggers.
- Level by total EP
- Saving rolls presumed to be LK; other stats optional but encouraged
- Saving rolls fail on natural rolls of 3 (⚀⚁) and 4 (⚀⚂) that aren't doubles

## 5.5 Edition

- attributes on 3d6 TARO
- Attributes ST DX CN IQ LK CH and optionally SP
- Types: Warrior, Wizard, Rogue, Warrior-Wizard
- Weapon damages presume 1d for daggers, 0D unarmed
- Combat Adds on St, Dex, Lk
- No spell schools
- Talents optional
- Level by total EP
- Saving rolls presumed to be LK; other stats optional but encouraged
- Saving rolls fail on natural rolls of 3 (⚀⚁) and 4 (⚀⚂) that aren't doubles

## 7.0 Main book

- attributes on 3d6 TARO
- Attributes ST DX CN IQ LK CH WZ SP
- Types: Warrior, Wizard, Rogue, Paragon, Citizen, Specialist (Specialist Mage, Leader, Ranger)
- Weapon damages presume 2d for daggers, 1D unarmed
- Combat Adds on St, Dex, Lk
- spell schools listed
- Talents optional, different from 5.5
- Level by highest of 4 attributes by type; EP raise attributes
- Saving rolls now on any attribute.
- Saving rolls fail on natural rolls of 3 (⚀⚁)

## 7.5 Main book

- attributes on 3d6 TARO
- Attributes ST DX CN IQ LK CH WZ SP
- Types: Warrior, Wizard, Rogue, Paragon, Citizen, Specialist (Specialist Mage, Leader, Ranger)
- Weapon damages presume 1d for daggers, 0D unarmed
- Combat Adds on St, Dex, Lk
- spell schools listed
- Talents optional, different from 5.5 and 7.0 (but close to 7.0)
- Level by highest of 4 attributes by type; EP raise attributes
- Saving rolls fail on natural rolls of 3 (⚀⚁)

## Deluxe

- attributes on 3d6 TARO
- Attributes ST DX CN IQ LK CH WZ SP
- Types: Warrior, Wizard, Rogue, Paragon, Citizen,
- Weapon damages presume 1d for daggers, 0D unarmed
- Combat Adds on St, Dex, Lk
- spell schools listed
- Talents optional, different from 5.5 and 7.0 (but close to 7.0), and can be (with very narrow limits) raised directly with EP.
- Level by highest of 4 attributes by type; EP raise attributes and talent bonuses.
- Extensive world background
- Saving rolls fail on natural rolls of 3 (⚀⚁)

Comment: As I am digging through D T&T in prep for a campaign in October, I am wondering if you played all of those editions ... may have a further question.

Comment: Yes, @KorvinStarmast. FTF: 5, 5.5, 7, 7.5, D; Solo: 4, 5, 5.5, 7, 7.5. I've also run a few sessions of the 4th derivative _Monsters! Monsters_ and the 5.0 derivative _MSPE_

Comment: Great. Can you take a peak at [the recent question I asked about Deluxe T&T?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156698/22566)  I am trying to get a fix on a weapon ruling to help my GM and to be smart about putting my Warrior together.  We have our first session on Monday and I want to have my character ready to go. (Also, in Deluxe, combat adds on str, speed, dex, and luck and I  think the text has AP (adventure points versus EP but same thing)

Answer (score 3):

I unfortunately have not played T&T and am unable to provide a full documentation of the patch notes, however here are some of the main differences between 5 and 7.5 based on information I can gather, and a quick read through the rule books for both.

---

System differences

- 7.5 contains separate magic casting and magic resistance stats, 5 uses Strength as the magical casting stat
- 7.5 contains more classes
- 7.5 uses a modified levelling system
- 7.5 introduces a "talent" system, as well as a more solid grasp of the "Stunts" system
- 7.5 is designed in general to be more structured
- Saving rolls are calculated differently between the 2 editions, but the final result is the same
- 7.5 Has more lenient systems for encumbrance, wielding weapons that are over weight and movement calculations.
- 5.5 Has more dynamic monster behaviour laid out in the rulebook, including reactions to players beyond attack till death.

---

Non system based differences

- 7.5 seems to assume a high degree of knowledge in it's rulebook of previous editions of the game
- From what I can gather the community seems to deem 5.5 as the superior version

Some more Information is available [Here](https://talesoftheramblingbumblers.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/tunnels-trolls-55-vs-75/) as this is one of the best articles on the subject I found.

Answer (score 3):

A key difference is that in versions 7 and above, monsters don’t lose attack dice as their MR is reduced — just the adds, which as usual are 1/2 of the current monster rating (MR).

In 5E, a monster with an MR of 100 that takes 90 damage (down to 10 MR) will drop from 11d6 plus 50 adds, to 2D6 plus 5 adds.   But in 7E and above, it will get its original 11D6, plus 5 adds.

This makes monsters somewhat more difficult to finish off, since they don’t lose attack dice as they take damage.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors in the Deluxe section in the answer from aramis, but I can't reply to it directly because I'm new here.

- Daggers are not 1D - the weakest dagger listed in the Daggers section is 2D, while the strongest is 2D+5.
- Unarmed combat is not 0D. It is 1D * the kindred's STR multiplier. So a Midgardian Dwarf with a *2 STR multiplier, gets 2D in unarmed. (For warriors, add their warrior bonus of 1D per level as well.)
- Combat adds are on STR, DEX, LK, and SPD as well. (SPD was left out above.)
- Level is not determined by highest of 4 attributes. It is determined by highest of all 8 attributes. If your highest attribute is 20, you're level 2. If your highest is 36, you're level 3, and so on. Doesn't matter which attribute.