# What do ability score limits for a Medium Spear refer to?

Tags: weapons, ability-scores, tunnels-and-trolls

In *Tunnels and Trolls, Deluxe Edition*, I am trying to find out if I even qualify for using a spear and shield as a Warrior.

The reason I ask is that I find a "/" with two different values for both Strength and Dexterity.  The rules text does not specify, and there is no "black diamond" {♦ ♦} designation for spears to indicate "can be used with one or two hands" (♦) or "can only be used with two hands" (♦ ♦). A number of large swords and pole arms have that designation, but the spear does not.

> SHAFTED WEAPONS
>
> The lighter spears may be thrown to good effect. Some variations are
>   particularly effective when used from horseback. The longer spears can
>   be less than useful in confined spaces. (T&T, Deluxe, p. 37)

In the table for spears, I find this (I left out spear thrower for brevity):

\begin{array}{r|ccc}  
\text{Weapon} & \text{Damage} & \text{STR} & \text{DEX} & \text{Cost}& \text{Weight} & \text{Range}\\  
\hline  
\text{Light spear} & \text{3d6} & \text{7} & \text{10/12} & \text{15}& \text{35} & \text{15} \\  
^\text{(Can be used with spear-thrower)} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{}& \text{} & \text{} \\  
\text{Mediuim Spear} & \text{4d6} & \text{12/14} & \text{8/12} & \text{50}& \text{100} & \text{20} \\  
\end{array}

I have a Strength of 12, and a Dexterity of 10.  I think I can use the Medium Spear (Str 12 and Dex 8 required) and a shield, but I think that I either can't use it from horseback, or I can't throw it, due to not having the Str 14 and Dex 12 that the Str 12/14 and Dex 8/12 seem to indicate. Any number of weapons have str and dex requirements that are currently beyond my character:  Pikes, S 15 D 12; Heroic Spear: S 18 D 12.

#### The Question to Answer

- Am I able to throw it, or not?
- Can I use it from horseback, or not?

  If somewhere in the rules the "/" is explained, please advise - it would help our GM.

  I have no recent experience with any T&T edition.  My last session was about 40 years ago, on an evening that included "Lets play Tunnels and Trolls!" and no small amount of beer.

#### Previous edition experience is helpful

If this was explained in a previous edition, that would be great to know and a useful point from which the GM can make a ruling.

#### The PC's Constraints

I rolled up 110 gold pieces for initial equipment. I am trying to put together a spear and shield (can afford with a few more items like a back pack with some stuff, boots, clothing ... ) or a sabre and shield (can afford but will arrive barefoot, with no other equipment beyond a shirt and pants). Class is Warrior.   The PC is sort average.  (She's named Eva Jorega - an anagram of *Joe Average* - based on all of her stat rolls being between 9 and 12, with a 13 in Luck - which struck me as ironic).
The Spear is cheaper, the two weapons do the same damage, but if I can throw it that add a combat option that the saber does not, so it would be an even better choice.

Comment: I have a sensible answer for this, but without the most current rule book in hand and a "word of god" backup from the game designers, I'm not prepaped for the storm of downvotes.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I expanded the question to clearly accept or welcome input from previous editions.  I have noted a variety of missing words and typos in Deluxe. If you've played the game, your experience in sorting this out may be helpful to us.  The GM is looking for a bit of old school flavor in this campaign....

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated that lore from previous editions is acceptable, there is this notation in the Tunnels and Trolls 5th edition:

> **Daggers**
>
> All daggers are one handed weapons. Some may be thrown, some may not. Therefore, in the *DEX Req* column there are two listings: The first is the DEX requirement to handle the dagger, the second number is the DEX requirement to throw it. When a dagger cannot be thrown, NA (Not Applicable) is used.

The spear charts for this edition, however, do not list separate requirements. If this nomenclature was carried over and applied to thrown spears as well as daggers, then your character would be able to handle and throw a light spear, but only be able to handle (not throw) a medium spear until your dexterity increases.

The 7th/30th anniversary edition also has the "/" designation added to the spear charts, but no explanation. Somewhere in that transition is where it appears the explanation was lost.

Answer (score 1):

The rules on page 32 of DT&T notes that the slash for STR/DEX on weapons lists is always melee/thrown

That neither has the ♦ nor ♦♦ is indicative that they are (quite historically correctly) 1-hand weapons. Historically, both were routinely used 1 handed.

The weapons table's requirements can be restated as

\begin{array}{r|ccccc}  
\text{Weapon} & \text{Use} & \text{Damage} & \text{STR} & \text{DEX} & \text{Cost}& \text{Weight} & \text{Range}\\  
\hline  
\text{Light spear} & \text{Melee} & \text{3d6} & \text{7} & \text{10} & \text{15}& \text{35} & \text{—} \\  
& \text{Ranged} &  \text{3d6} & \text{7} & \text{12} &&& \text{15} \\
\hline
\text{Mediuim Spear} & \text{Melee}  & \text{4d6} & \text{12} & \text{8} & \text{50}& \text{100} & \text{—} \\  
& \text{Ranged}  & \text{4d6} & \text{14} & \text{12} &&& \text{20} \\  
\hline
\end{array}

Thus your Str 12 Dx 10 Character can melee with either, but cannot throw either. And that melee is 1-handed, and often with a spear. Various medieval martial arts groups have demonstrated a 7' x 1.25" diameter ratan spear used 1-handed often enough for me. And that's in the Medium Spear range.

The penalties for too hard weapons are different for melee and ranged. In Ranged, it is just an automatic miss. In Melee, it's a -1 to damage per missing point, for up to five points, then "cannot wield," along with an escalating saving throw. (see DT&T, page 51, *Unwieldy Weapons*)

Noting this, note also the two weapons rule: you need the sum of the required scores. So a hypothetical STR 19 DEX 20 Can wield two light spears (STR 7+7=14 & DEX 10+10), or even a light and a medium (STR 7+12=19 & DEX 10+8=18), he can only throw one or the other. He can, however, throw a light while meleeing with a heavy (STR 7+12=19 & DEX 12+8=20) but cannot throw the medium and melee with the light (STR 7+14=21 & DEX 10+12=22).

Comment: Note that DT&T does a number of things different from prior; Weapon Penalties, Spell Schools, Specialists... and including setting material. Most spears haven't needed 2 hands to use in prior editions.

Comment: My back up character rolle Triple 1's on the IQ, so she is a specialist. (She got a 9 on her second roll, but sadly not a triple 3)

Comment: That took you explaining to me to make sense.  Thanks!  *Certain weapons
have two DEX requirements listed, in which case the second is the DEX required to use it as a missile weapon (a thrown axe or knife, for example)*  That it applies to STR also makes sense, but as it wasn't explicit I am glad I asked.